# ImageCarousel component overlaps content below when image aspect ratio changes in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a React app that features an ImageCarousel component that displays a set of images. The component works fine when all of the images have the same aspect ratio, but when the aspect ratio changes, the carousel overlaps the content that comes after it.

I've tried setting the height of the container div using padding-bottom with a percentage value based on the image's aspect ratio, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the relevant code for the component:

```
type ImageCarouselProps = {
  images: ImageType[];
};

type ImageDimension = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
};

export default function ImageCarousel({ images }: ImageCarouselProps) {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<ImageDimension>({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });
  const [paddingBottom, setPaddingBottom] = useState(0);

  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedRight: () => prevSlide(),
    onSwipedLeft: () => nextSlide(),
    trackMouse: true

  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    if (!containerRef.current) return;
    const img = new Image();
    images[0]?.url && (img.src = images[0].url);
    console.log(img.src);
    img.onload = () => {
      setDimensions({
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height
      });
    };
  }, [images, containerRef.current]);

  const prevSlide = () => {
    const isFirstSlide = currentIndex === 0;
    const newIndex = isFirstSlide ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    const isLastSlide = currentIndex === images.length - 1;
    const newIndex = isLastSlide ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const goToSlide = (slideIndex: number) => {
    setCurrentIndex(slideIndex);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="relative flex justify-center items-center w-full"
      style={{
        height: 0,
        paddingBottom: `${(dimensions.height / dimensions.width) * 100}%`
      }}
      //q:the code above doesnt work on the last image in the feed give me a way to fix it
      //a
      ref={containerRef}
    >
      <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full" {...handlers}>
        <NextImage
          src={images[currentIndex]?.url || ""}
          alt={`Image ${currentIndex + 1}`}
          width={dimensions.width}
          height={dimensions.height}
          className="transition-opacity duration-500 ease-out"
        />
      </div>
      {images.length === 1 ? null : (
        <>
          <div className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-3 z-10">
            <div className="rounded-full bg-gray-300/30 cursor-pointer p-1">
              <BsChevronCompactLeft onClick={prevSlide} size={15} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 right-3 z-10">
            <div className="rounded-full bg-gray-300/30 cursor-pointer p-1">
              <BsChevronCompactRight onClick={nextSlide} size={15} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      <div
        className="absolute w-full text-center bottom-3"
      >
        {images.map((_, index) => (
          <RxDotFilled
            key={index}
            size={20}
            className={`mx-1 cursor-pointer ${
              index === currentIndex ? "text-gray-300" : "text-gray-500"
            }`}
            onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}
```

And here's how I'm rendering the component in another part of the app:

```
// SomeOtherComponent.js

import ImageCarousel from './ImageCarousel';

function SomeOtherComponent({ post }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Some other content */}
      <ImageCarousel images={post.images} />
      {/* More content */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SomeOtherComponent;
```

Any ideas on how I can prevent the carousel from overlapping content below it when the aspect ratio of the images changes? Thanks in advance!

I've tried setting the height of the container div using padding-bottom with a percentage value based on the image's aspect ratio, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Have an `onLoad` listener on the `<NextImage>` component to update the `dimensions` using `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`, since `width` and `height` will be from the image's already set attributes:

```
const onLoad = ({ target }) => {
  setDimensions({
    width: target.naturalWidth,
    height: target.naturalHeight,
  });
};

// …
<NextImage
  // …
  onLoad={onLoad}
/>
```

This will ensure the `dimensions` data is for the image being shown, and will properly update the `padding-bottom` style.

See a live example on [this StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-kshqrh?file=pages/index.js).